# Forcibly running into an enemy during movement

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, forced-movement

Playing 5e. Can you make an attack and then use your movement to charge an enemy, knocking him over, pushing him back, or otherwise harrowing him to help your teammate? Seems totally logical. I slice they guy I’m fighting down, see my buddy in trouble and with my movement rush over and run into his guy. In life that would be you moving but in 5e it seems like an attack or some sort of feat. I think I’ve answered my own question but, thoughts?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Good first question! Take a look at the [tour] when you're free.

Answer (score 11):

#### Shove.

Make a [shove attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#ShovingaCreature) using the Attack action:

> ##### Shoving a Creature
>
> Using the Attack action, you can make a special melee attack to shove a creature, either to knock it prone or push it away from you. If you’re able to make multiple attacks with the Attack action, this attack replaces one of them.
>
> The target must be no more than one size larger than you and must be within your reach. Instead of making an attack roll, you make a Strength (Athletics) check contested by the target’s Strength (Athletics) or Dexterity (Acrobatics) check (the target chooses the ability to use). You succeed automatically if the target is incapacitated. If you succeed, you either knock the target prone or push it 5 feet away from you.

And if you want to be really good at shoving, consider taking the Charger feat:

> When you use your action to Dash, you can use a bonus action to make one melee weapon attack or to shove a creature.
>
> If you move at least 10 feet in a straight line immediately before taking this bonus action, you either gain a +5 bonus to the attack’s damage roll (if you chose to make a melee attack and hit) or push the target up to 10 feet away from you (if you chose to shove and you succeed).

Finally, the *Dungeon Master’s Guide* has an *optional* (so ask your DM) rule called Shove Aside:

> ##### Shove Aside
>
> With this option, a creature uses the special shove attack from the Player’s Handbook to force a target to the side, rather than away. The attacker has disadvantage on its Strength (Athletics) check when it does so. If that check is successful, the attacker moves the target 5 feet to a different space within its reach.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin Extra Attack will allow PC's to make multiple attacks on their turn when they take the Attack action, and the rules explain that these attacks can be broken up by movement.  So it would be possible to slice a guy, then rush over and shove attack a different opponent, if your Extra attack gave you the ability to make two attacks.  Thomas Markov might mention that explicitly and I think doing so would improve his answer.  But it also helps to clarify for the OP that the shove attack would _not_ be a function of movement _per se_.

Comment: Thanks! So, to be clear, in real life it’d be no biggie to hit someone then go running into someone else. But in dnd the running into would have to be an attack, so without a second attack or some similar feat as described above, this is not possible in gameplay. Got it! Thanks again!

Comment: @Casey Even in real life both of those things take time.

Comment: Agreed, but if in dnd I can hit someone and then move 30’, in real like I could end that move by running into someone.